# Ruby difference between statements

Tags: ruby, search, nested-attributes, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using Solr to search for a list of companies. when I try to filter

Works

```
  companies = []
  current_user.cached_company.cached_companies.each do |company|
    companies << company.id
  end
```

Doesn't Work

```
  companies = []
  companies << current_user.cached_company.cached_companies.map(&:id)
```

When I call

```
  @search = Company.search do 
    with :id, companies
  end
  @companies = @search
```

It works with the first example but not the second.

However, this works just fine

```
  @search = Company.search do 
    with :id, current_user.cached_company.cached_companies.map(&:id)
  end
  @companies = @search
```

I know that I'm missing something simple here. I know it doesn't have to do with the caching, but cannot wrap my head around what's going on.

Comment: When I mean that it does not work, I mean that the Solr Search returns an error (id is not a multiple-value field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is putting a nested array in `companies`. Here's a simplified idea of what's going on:

```
data = [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}]

foo = []
data.each do |number|
  foo << number[:value]
end
p foo
# => [1,2,3] # One array with 3 values

foo = []
foo << data.map { |item| item[:value] }
p foo
# => [[1,2,3]] # One array with one value (another array with 3 values)
```

Either stick with your first version, or just do this:

```
companies = current_user.cached_company.cached_companies.map(&:id)
```

Or, if you want to stick with your 2nd version, make sure to flatten the values before you use them:

```
companies.flatten!
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan. That works. I didn't realize that it was doing that. Any thoughts on performance as to which one would be more efficient?